# Creating a 'artificial' button

Tags: button, arduino

I'm actually really not sure about this, but how can I create a no moving parts button. As in when I send a certain byte using the Serial.read() it will connect two channels for about a second then close the connection.

*Sorry 
I am using a Ardunio mega board. (Can't tag it because the tag doesn't exist)

Comment: `Serial.read()`? I think you need to add another tag to your question, or at least tell us what you are using...

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `Arduino` and tagging appropriately

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by a "channel". Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to [use a transistor as a switch](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_4/2.html). Connect an Arduino pin to the base and you can switch it on and off using `digitalWrite()`. I don't think this can be done completely without hardware. But a transistor does not have any moving parts at least.